# Load Drools Guided Decision Table to Java List/Map

Tags: java, drools, business-rules, brms, redhat-bpm

Hi I was wondering if there is a way to load all the content of the guided decision table to java collection (list/map)? I achieved this by making each rule(row) calling a java method where I add this to a hashmap but performance-wise is really bad I was wondering if there is a better way to do so. Thanks in advance!

[image: Guided Desion Table]

[![enter image description here]

```
   package MyPkg;

import com.abc.por.model.Bborder;
import com.abc.por.utils.BborderUtil;
import com.abc.por.utils.MyUtil;
import com.abc.por.model.constants.FE;

//from row number: 1
//PRE_Regression
rule "Row 1 HPDT"
    @RuleName(OnlyOnePharmacy)
    no-loop true
    lock-on-active true
    ruleflow-group "HighPayer"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        borderUtil : BborderUtil( )
        Bborder( src : src == "SPECIAL" )
        border : Bborder( requestDateTime >= "24-Dec-2020" , requestDateTime < "03-May-2022" )
    then
        MyUtil myUtil = new MyUtil();
        myUtil.setPlanCode( "RGC" );
        myUtil.setPlanType( "RGC" );
        myUtil.setFeIndicator( "NO" );
        myUtil.setPharmacies( "RED" );
        insert( myUtil );
        modify( borderUtil ) {
                setRuleFired( true )
        }
        borderUtil.populateDrugDataToMap( null, myUtil, border );
        retract( myUtil);
end

//from row number: 2
//PRE_Regression
rule "Row 2 HPDT"
    @RuleName(SinglePharmacy)
    no-loop true
    lock-on-active true
    ruleflow-group "HighPayer"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        borderUtil : BborderUtil( )
        Bborder( src : src == "SPECIAL" )
        border : Bborder( requestDateTime >= "24-Dec-2020" )
    then
        MyUtil myUtil = new MyUtil();
        myUtil.setPlanCode( "RGA" );
        myUtil.setPlanType( "RGA" );
        myUtil.setFeIndicator( "NO" );
        myUtil.setPharmacies( "MPT,RED" );
        insert( myUtil );
        modify( borderUtil ) {
                setRuleFired( true )
        }
        borderUtil.populateDrugDataToMap( null, myUtil, border );
        retract( myUtil);
end

//from row number: 3
//PRE_Regression
rule "Row 3 HPDT"
    @RuleName(FE=BE)
    no-loop true
    lock-on-active true
    ruleflow-group "HighPayer"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        borderUtil : BborderUtil( )
        Bborder( src : src == "SPECIAL" )
        border : Bborder( requestDateTime >= "24-Dec-2020" )
    then
        MyUtil myUtil = new MyUtil();
        myUtil.setPlanCode( "RGB" );
        myUtil.setPlanType( "RGB" );
        myUtil.setFeIndicator( "YES" );
        myUtil.setPharmacies( "MPT,RED" );
        insert( myUtil );
        modify( borderUtil ) {
                setRuleFired( true )
        }
        borderUtil.populateDrugDataToMap( null, myUtil, border );
        retract( myUtil);
end
```

Comment: What exactly are you dumping into a map? Actually, better question -- what is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thank you for your response I'm just trying to read decision table data so I can use these data to do some processing.

Comment: Since the decision table is just an excel file, why not just load its contents and dump it into whatever data structure you need (eg via Apache POI or your favorite excel parsing library?)

Comment: This gdst table

Comment: OK, so basically XML. Even easier.

Comment: yeah, but how to locate the decision table from kjar?

Comment: kjar is just a jar which is just a zip file.

Comment: ... though looking back at these comments, what kind of "processing" requires a map?